# How do I sort an array while preserving the Order

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array e.g. 3,4,3,1,5

Sorting in Ascending or descending order gives 1,3,3,4,5 or 5,4,3,3,1.

I need the original order e.g. 3,3,4,1,5

underscoreJs has the groupBy method, but that splits the array up into the groups.

Any ideas?

Comment: what qualifies a group?

Comment: questionData.questions = _.chain(questionData.questions)
    .sortBy('category')
    .each(function (resultNew, indexNew) {
     resultNew.order = indexNew + 1;
    })
    .sortBy('order')
    .value();

Comment: Clone the original array!?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem, especially given the extra context in that code comment. You're probably not _actually_ sorting just numbers, are you?

Comment: E.g. we could replace the sortBy('category') with groupBy('category'). but that changes the format of the output.

Comment: Correct. But I'm sorting on the Category, which is a number

Comment: It is not clear what order you need... Do you want to order the array by array key?

Comment: I'm ordering on the 'Category' of each array element, which has a numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the array in place, you can get the priority for each item and `sort` it using the priority object

```js
let array = [3, 4, 3, 1, 5],
    index = 0,
    priority = {};
      
array.forEach(n => priority[n] = priority[n] || ++index);
array.sort((a, b) => priority[a] - priority[b])

console.log(array)
```

If you want a new array, you could create a `counter` object which counts the occurrence. Then, create another array based on the count of each number

```js
const 
    array = [3, 4, 3, 1, 5],
    counter = array.reduce((acc, n) => acc.set(n, acc.get(n) + 1 || 1), new Map),
    output = Array.from(counter).flatMap(([n, count]) => Array(count).fill(n))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
const arr = [3, 4, 3, 1, 5];

const result = arr.sort((a, b) => a === b || arr.indexOf(a) - arr.indexOf(b));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: questionData.questions = _.chain(questionData.questions)
    .sortBy('category')
    .each(function (resultNew, indexNew) {
     resultNew.order = indexNew + 1;
    })
    .sortBy('order')
    .value();

Comment: I'm not actually sorting on 3,4,3,1,5 , I'm sorting on a 'Category' property of an array which has those values.  How can this be applied the the above?

Comment: I guess `questionData.questions.sort((a, b) => a.category === b.category || questionData.questions.indexOf(a) - questionData.questions.indexOf(b));`

Comment: That hasn't changed hasn't grouped them at all.

Comment: Oh, and groupBy also orders on Category, which I don't want it to do. I need it to keep the existing order, just group them together.

Comment: You can post the object or an object with the same structure and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quite long-winded solution which works but will could do with refining.

```
             var tempQuestions = [];

            // For each Question.
            _.each(questionData.questions, function (resultCategory, indexCategory) {
                // Get other Question for the same Category, and push to new Array.
                tempQuestions.push(_.filter(questionData.questions, function (num) {
                    return num.category === resultCategory.category;
                }));
                // Remove all Question for the processes Cateogory (these are now stored in the tempQuestions)
                questionData.questions = _.filter(questionData.questions, function (item) {
                    return item.category !== resultCategory.category;
                });
            });

            // The above processing will create some unwanted blank arrays, remove them.
            tempQuestions = _.filter(tempQuestions, function (num) {
                return num.length !== 0;
            });

            // Flatten the array structure to match the original.
            questionData.questions = _(tempQuestions).chain()
                .zip()
                .flatten()
                .value();
```